# julia - select on a wrapper series using a range of datetimes

Tags: julia

How do you implement the required getters and setters to do a select on a range of datetimes on a wrapper series of vector.

```
mutable struct Series{T} <: AbstractArray{T,2}
    data::Vector{Vector{Int}}
end

series[startDateTime:endDateTime, :]
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to define new array methods specific to your data type.

For an example:

```
Base.size(s::Series) = (length(s.data), length(s.data) == 0 ? 0 :  length(s.data[1]))
Base.getindex(s::Series, idx::Vararg{Int,2}) = s.data[idx[1]][idx[2]]
Base.setindex!(s::Series{T}, val::T, idx::Vararg{Int,2}) where T = s.data[idx[1]][idx[2]] = Int(val)
```

Now you can do

```
julia> s = Series{Int}([[1,2],[3,4],[5,6]])
3×2 Series{Int64}:
 1  2
 3  4
 5  6

julia> s[1:end, :]
3×2 Matrix{Int64}:
 1  2
 3  4
 5  6

julia> s[2:end, :]
2×2 Matrix{Int64}:
 3  4
 5  6
```

Regarding datetimes regarding on your application you would need to decide how to convert them to integer indices. You can see that types for getindex are customizable.
For an example:

```
Base.getindex(s::Series, idx::Vararg{DateTime,2}) = s.data[(year(idx[1]) % 3)+1][(year(idx[2]) % 3)+1]

julia> s[now(), now()]
4
```

For ranges you could easiest use milliseconds (depends on the application).

Finally there is a TimeSeries package that perhaps has the functionality that you need:

```
using TimeSeries 
dates = Date(2018, 1, 1):Day(1):Date(2018, 12, 31)
ta = TimeArray(dates, rand(length(dates)))
```

And you can do:

```
julia> ta[Date("2018-01-05"):Date("2018-01-07")]
3×1 TimeArray{Float64, 1, Date, Vector{Float64}} 2018-01-05 to 2018-01-07
│            │ A      │
├────────────┼────────┤
│ 2018-01-05 │ 0.8879 │
│ 2018-01-06 │ 0.217  │
│ 2018-01-07 │ 0.0813 │
```